# How to present a View after tapping an ActionSheet.Button in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've been playing around with SwiftUI and got stumped on this simple thing. Basically, I'm trying to trigger a modal after tapping on an `ActionSheet.Button`. Here's my code so far:

```
struct SomePage: View {
    @State var showSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showSheet = true
        }) { 
            Text("Show ation sheet") 
        }.presentation(sheet)
    }

    private var sheet: ActionSheet? {
        let button = ActionSheet.Button.default(Text("Button") {
             self.showSheet = false
             // what now??
        }
        let action = ActionSheet(title: Text("Title"),
                                 message: nil,
                                 buttons: [button])
        return showSheet ? action : nil
    }

    // This is the modal I'm trying to present 
    // after tapping on the action sheet button
    private var modal: Modal {
        return Modal(SomePage())
    }
}
```

I've tried adding a second `presentation` handler to the button and toggling a `showModal` property but obviously the debugger complained about attempting a second modal presentation while the first one was still being presented.

Does anybody have an idea on how to make this work?

Comment: Simple action sheet event : https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2019/09/swiftui-actionsheet-example.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not far off from it.

Add another `@State` to handle the presentation of the modal.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var showSheet = false
    @State var showModal = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showSheet = true
        }) {
            Text("Show action sheet")
        }
        .actionSheet(isPresented: $showSheet, content: actionSheet)
        .sheet(isPresented: $showModal, content: { Text("Modal") })
    }

    private func actionSheet() -> ActionSheet {
        let button = ActionSheet.Button.default(Text("Show modal")) {
            self.showSheet = false
            self.showModal = true
        }
        let actionSheet = ActionSheet(title: Text("Action Sheet"),
                                      message: nil,
                                      buttons: [button])
        return actionSheet
    }

}
```

**Result**:

[image]

**Updated for Xcode 11 beta 5**

Comment: Thankts! Is using GDC and timeout the "official" way to do this, though?

Comment: @GrzegorzAperliński I forgot to get rid of that code - it seemed like a good idea at first (to give SwiftUI some breathing room to update itself), but it seems the framework handles that automatically.

Comment: Thanks! You're right. It's working like a charm – what I was missing was setting the presentation flag back to `false` in the onDismiss handler. Kinda thought that would happen magically :D

Comment: Only one weird thing I've noticed happening – if there are two buttons and each is hooked up to a modal presentation trigger, only the second one works. Haven't figured out why yet.

Comment: This weird thing is still here. Having been testing, trying and searching for hours until I found this post.